# Enable code collapsing on AvalonEdit control

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I try to enable code collapsing on AvalonEdit control and I can not enable it properly.

```
public FoldingManager foldingManager;
public XmlFoldingStrategy foldingStrategy;
```

to enable code collapsing I insert this code on Window_Loaded

```
foldingManager = FoldingManager.Install(textEditor.TextArea);
foldingStrategy = new XmlFoldingStrategy();
foldingStrategy.UpdateFoldings(foldingManager, textEditor.Document);
```

and to update the collapsing I insert to textEditor_TextChanged this code

```
foldingStrategy.UpdateFoldings(foldingManager, textEditor.Document);
```

from the Window_Loaded I get only the first collapsing to work (like in the picture the other tags not updated)

the code in textEditor_TextChanged does not work at all

[image: Code folding example]

Answer (score 3):

Your document is not a valid XML document: XML only allows one top-level element, but you have two (`<head>` and `<body>`).

`XmlFoldingStrategy` can therefore only fold the valid part of the document.
If you want HTML folding, you'll need to write your own `HtmlFoldingStrategy`.

If you're OK with forcing the HTML to be valid XML, you'll have to add the opening `<html>` tag.